# Given that I have a list of vector <1, 2, 3, 4>, can next_permutation in algorithm library help me arrange 4P2 arrangement? In C++

Tags: c++

can `next_permutation` avoid the duplication as what I want is to skip 2th and 4th as only change in first 2 character is important to me.

```
do {  
   //Do something
} while(next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
```

this will get 4! = 24 solution, while I only wanted 4P2 = 12 solution.

The above coding will give me.

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 4 3 
1 3 2 4 
1 3 4 2 
1 4 2 3 
1 4 3 2 
2 1 3 4 
2 1 4 3 
2 3 1 4 
2 3 4 1 
2 4 1 3 
2 4 3 1 
3 1 2 4 
3 1 4 2 
3 2 1 4 
3 2 4 1 
3 4 1 2 
3 4 2 1 
4 1 2 3 
4 1 3 2 
4 2 1 3 
4 2 3 1 
4 3 1 2 
4 3 2 1
```

While actually I only want

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 3
2 4
3 1
3 2
3 4
4 1
4 2
4 3
```

Comment: @user17732522 the 4 permute 2 kind, where u have 4 character, but I only want to arrange them into 2 slot

Comment: ah sry, I wanted to describe the only change in first 2 character is important to me.

Comment: `next_permutation(s.begin(), s.begin() + 2)`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thats not generating the set OP looks for. It will generate only two items: `1 2` and `2 1`.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm glad you know what they're looking for as  I'm not sure anyone else does

Comment: @user17732522 ok thanks, I guess this function is only more suitable for direct permutation only

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you want to **ignore** permutations of the 3rd and 4th element? That sounds like you want to nest 2 `std::next_permutation` loops.

Comment: @MSalters what I want is like what user17732522 said, drawing all ordered k-tuples out of a set of n

Comment: @RenSword Sorry, my previous comment was not correct.

Comment: They want to draw all (ordered) k-tuples with distinct entries out of a set of n, where here k=2 and n=4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do {
   // Do something with the first two entries of `s`.
   std::prev_permutation(s.begin()+2, s.end());
} while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
```

This will essentially skip all permutations of the last two items, so it won't iterate all permutations unnecessarily and be relatively efficient even if you change the length of the vector or the number of items you are interested in (the magic number `2` in the code above).

Comment: Left to the reader: define a `next_permutation(begin, end, k)` overload.

Comment: @RenSword You always just want to skip all permutations of the last two items. `prev_permutation` just basically does the permutation in the opposite order directly giving the last one. It should be relatively obvious if you go through it by hand in the list you posted in the question. For 2 out of 4 items this isn't really necessary, you could just skip every second permutation, but I assume you want a generic solution that will also work for other numbers.

Comment: @user17732522 I wanted to use it for other values as well, thanks.